# Cannot connect xtion pro live with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, openni

I need to work with asus xtion pro live to detect hand movements and objects. I am an amateur as far as it concerns programming this camera.

My problem is how to connect them and from where to start.

I work on Ubuntu 12.04. I've downloaded Ros fuerte and both Openni2 and OpenCV. When i plug the camera (usb port) and run the lsusb command, i see this:

"Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1d27:0601 "

Even when i run the command $ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

i get:

[ INFO] [1415717730.873978521]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.6/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 61 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: USB interface is not supported!

Can anyone please help? Is there a problem with the camera driver?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run the openni2 samples? what version of openni2 did you installed?

Comment: I've installed OpenNI 2.2.0.33 for 64-bit system. The samples do not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must go to a terminal and do

```
sudo nano /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini
```

and there find `UsbInterface` and make sure it is not a comment (without ; at the beginning) and that is equal to 2

```
UsbInterface=2
```

I heard that this may give you problems with Kinect hardware (the same error you are getting now). But, if you use the Kinect later on and gives this problem, just comment it and it should work

```
;UsbInterface=2
```

You must reboot every time you change this value!!

I hope this works for you ;)

Comment: Thank you for you time!! I did what you told me and now i get this problem:     Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!                                                               Is there anything else i could do?

Comment: Hmmmm, first time I encounter such an error. What version of openni2 are you using? googling it, says it is that the camera is not in full speed, but also I think this was corrected in the latest version (I may be wrong) so maybe updating to the latest version can work

Comment: i updated to the last version and still nothing. i cannot connect the camera and i cannot see it even with lausb (get the same message as above).

Comment: @ΜαρίαΤσούρμα same message but with different version right? can you try with `UsbInterface=0` instead of 2, that worked in some computers, though I think your case is the 2 since is newer.

Comment: I managed to connect my camera with a raspberry Pi. Raspberry sees my camera and xtion pro live works fine. Thank you for your help!